# How can I exclude directories matching certain patterns from the output of the Linux 'find' command?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to use regex's with Linux's `find` command to dive recursively into a gargantuan directory tree, showing me all of the .c, .cpp, and .h files, but omitting matches containing certain substrings.  Ultimately I want to send the output to an `xargs` command to do certain processing on all of the matching files.  I can pipe the `find` output through grep to remove matches containing those substrings, but that solution doesn't work so well with filenames that contain spaces.  So I tried using `find`'s -print0 option, which terminates each filename with a nul char instead of a newline (whitespace), and using `xargs -0` to expect nul-delimited input instead of space-delimited input, but I couldn't figure out how to pass the nul-delimited `find` through the piped grep filters successfully; grep -Z didn't seem to help in that respect.

So I figured I'd just write a better regex for `find` and do away with the intermediary `grep` filters... perhaps `sed` would be an alternative?

In any case, for the following small sampling of directories...

```
./barney/generated/bam bam.h
./barney/src/bam bam.cpp
./barney/deploy/bam bam.h
./barney/inc/bam bam.h
./fred/generated/dino.h
./fred/src/dino.cpp
./fred/deploy/dino.h
./fred/inc/dino.h
```

...I want the output to include all of the .h, .c, and .cpp files but NOT those ones that appear in the 'generated' and 'deploy' directories.

BTW, you can create an entire test directory (named fredbarney) for testing solutions to this question by cutting & pasting this whole line into your bash shell:

```
mkdir fredbarney; cd fredbarney; mkdir fred; cd fred; mkdir inc; mkdir docs; mkdir generated; mkdir deploy; mkdir src; echo x > inc/dino.h; echo x > docs/info.docx; echo x > generated/dino.h; echo x > deploy/dino.h; echo x > src/dino.cpp; cd ..; mkdir barney; cd barney; mkdir inc; mkdir docs; mkdir generated; mkdir deploy; mkdir src; echo x > 'inc/bam bam.h'; echo x > 'docs/info info.docx'; echo x > 'generated/bam bam.h'; echo x > 'deploy/bam bam.h'; echo x > 'src/bam bam.cpp'; cd ..;
```

This command finds all of the .h, .c, and .cpp files...

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(c|cpp|h)$"
```

...but if I pipe its output through xargs, the 'bam bam' files each get treated as two separate (nonexistant) filenames (note that here I'm simply using `ls` as a stand-in for what I actually want to do with the output):

```
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(c|cpp|h)$" | xargs -n 1 ls
ls: ./barney/generated/bam: No such file or directory
ls: bam.h: No such file or directory
ls: ./barney/src/bam: No such file or directory
ls: bam.cpp: No such file or directory
ls: ./barney/deploy/bam: No such file or directory
ls: bam.h: No such file or directory
ls: ./barney/inc/bam: No such file or directory
ls: bam.h: No such file or directory
./fred/generated/dino.h
./fred/src/dino.cpp
./fred/deploy/dino.h
./fred/inc/dino.h
```

So I can enhance that with the -print0 and -0 args to `find` and `xargs`:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(c|cpp|h)$" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
./barney/generated/bam bam.h
./barney/src/bam bam.cpp
./barney/deploy/bam bam.h
./barney/inc/bam bam.h
./fred/generated/dino.h
./fred/src/dino.cpp
./fred/deploy/dino.h
./fred/inc/dino.h
```

...which is great, except that I don't want the 'generated' and 'deploy' directories in the output.  So I try this:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(c|cpp|h)$" -print0 | grep -v generated | grep -v deploy | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
barney  fred
```

...which clearly does not work.  So I tried using the -Z option with grep (not knowing exactly what the -Z option really does) and that didn't work either.  So I figured I'd write a better regex for `find` and this is the best I could come up with:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "(?!.*(generated|deploy).*$)(.+\.(c|cpp|h)$)" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
```

...but bash didn't like that (!.*: event not found, whatever that means), and even if that weren't an issue, my regex doesn't seem to work on the regex tester web page I normally use.

Any ideas how I can make this work?  This is the output I want:

```
$ find . [----options here----] | [----maybe grep or sed----] | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
./barney/src/bam bam.cpp
./barney/inc/bam bam.h
./fred/src/dino.cpp
./fred/inc/dino.h
```

...and I'd like to avoid scripts & temporary files, which I suppose might be my only option.

Thanks in advance!
-Mark

Comment: The `event not found` is because `!` is being interpreted as a request for history expansion by `bash`. Single-quote the string it appears in, or give it an additional escape. I recommend single quoting!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.+\.(c|cpp|h)$' -not -path '*/generated/*' \
       -not -path '*/deploy/*' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -L1d
```

Changes from your version are minimal: I added exclusions of certain path patterns separately, because that's easier, and I single-quote things to hide them from shell interpolation.

The event not found is because `!` is being interpreted as a request for history expansion by `bash`. The fix is to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Pop quiz: What characters are special inside of a single-quoted string in `sh`?

Answer: ***Only*** `'` is special (it ends the string). That's the ultimate safety.

`grep` with `-Z` (sometimes known as `--null`) makes `grep` **output** terminated with a null character instead of newline. What you wanted was `-z` (sometimes known as `--null-data`) which causes `grep` to interpret a null character in its **input** as end-of-line instead of a newline character. This makes it work as expected with the output of `find ... -print0`, which adds a null character after each file name instead of a newline.

If you had done it this way:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.+\.(c|cpp|h)$' -print0 | \
    grep -vzZ generated | grep -vzZ deploy | xargs -0 ls -1Ld
```

Then the input *and* output of `grep` would have been null-delimited and it would have worked correctly... until one of your source files began being named `deployment.cpp` and started getting "mysteriously" excluded by your script.

Incidentally, here's a nicer way to generate your testcase file set.

```
while read -r file ; do
    mkdir -p "${file%/*}"
    touch "$file"
done <<'DATA'
./barney/generated/bam bam.h
./barney/src/bam bam.cpp
./barney/deploy/bam bam.h
./barney/inc/bam bam.h
./fred/generated/dino.h
./fred/src/dino.cpp
./fred/deploy/dino.h
./fred/inc/dino.h
DATA
```

Since I did this anyway to verify I figured I'd share it and save you from repetition. Don't do anything twice! That's what computers are for.

Answer (score 0):

Your command:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "(?!.*(generated|deploy).*$)(.+\.(c|cpp|h)$)" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
```

fails because you are trying to use `Posix extended regular expressions`, which dont support lookaround/lookbehind etc. https://superuser.com/a/596499/658319

`find` does support `pcre`, so if you convert to `pcre`, this should work.